# Trying to do test automation for Revit plugin but WinAppDriver is not recognising Revit elements

Tags: revit-api, winappdriver

Has anyone done test automation for Revit? What tools did you use?

WinappDriver is able to open revit window but is not able to recognise the elements inside it

Answer (score 0):

Your Revit add-in can only run inside a running Revit.exe session, and the Revit API is completely event-driven, and only Revit.exe can raise the corresponding events, so it is a bit tricky to drive it by a unit testing framework. There are several ways to work around this, though. A few of them are discussed by [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) in the topic group on [Unit Testing](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.16).